# asp.net How to resume button's postback after ajax completion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, button

I have a button and have postback function as btnSubmit.Click in the code behind.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit"  UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClientClick="ajaxCall(); return false;" />
```

Now, i want to do a pre-post action, which will call an ajax to do some calculation, and have a confirmation box to allow user to click "Ok" - resume original button's function do to the postback, or "Cancel" - simply just cancel the postback.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ajaxCall() {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "ODS.aspx/ClientCall",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }, error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

I kept getting either only fire the confirmation box, but the "OK" won't work, or the postback will over the ajax. I know there must be a smart way to do this, to interrupt the normal button submit postback behavior, but don't want to introduce more controls, something like hiddenbutton or so, feels like very hacky way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know weather it will solve your problem or not but you can use ajaxStart and ajaxStop method and in those methods you can write your logic of confirmation..

Comment: those all for the ajax function, but I want to call the initial button's postback function after the ajax completion, so the ajax function is just a pre-submit check or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Another option from ajaxStart and ajaxStop and jquery .after().

Is if you were to use a ASP:LinkButton you can store the href property in a variable, remove it when the client clicks, when you need it to execute just do eval([HREFVariable]).

This is from memory but I am going to look it up in a minute:

```
$('a.whatever').on("click", function(){
e.preventDefault();//stop the post back
var defaultAction = $(this).prop("href");

//do stuff

//you are ready now
eval(defaultAction);

});
```

This works because ASP.Net does postbacks in the href like javascript:__doPostBack(...);

So this just calls the function you were going to do.

**Edit 2** Since you want to stay with the asp:button

Something like this should work

```
$('a.whatever').on("click", function(){
    e.preventDefault();//stop the post back
    var id = $(this).prop('id');


    //do stuff

//you are ready now
__doPostBack(id, '');

});
```

I am guessing on this part though. This should fire the correct post back, but I have not tested it.

Comment: what if it's just a regular button, not any linkButton? So the matter is how could I re-invoke the postback function after an ajax completion, I could stop the post by doing e.preventdDefault().

Comment: I updated it for a ASP:Button, I think it should work.

Comment: somehow it doesn't hit my event delegation in the postback, it does the postback now....wired..

Comment: Yea, its because the second part of __doPostBack is the event argurment. I am trying to figure out how to fire the click event. It might just be "click".

Comment: I think I know whats wrong $(this).prop('ID') should be $(this).prop('id'). jQuery.prop is case sensitive. My Bad.

Comment: not really...still the same just a simple postback which didn't hit the button's event...

Comment: var you calling $(this).prop('id') inside another function like inside the ajaxCall? If so it wouldn't work. You would need to make a variable like just below e.preventDefault(); to store the id and then pass it that way.

Comment: $('.btnSubmit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).prop('id');
            var app_id = <%=app_id %>;
            ts.checkGPA(app_id, function (r) {
            if (r) {
                __doPostBack(id, '');
            } else {
                if(confirm("You do not meet the eligibility requirements to apply with the information you have entered. Are you sure you would to submit?")) {
                __doPostBack(id, 'OnClick');
                }
            }
            });
        });

Comment: I'm totally guessing at this point. My harddrive fired this morning so I am in the middle of reinstalling everything and can't test anything.
I am almost out of guesses but try __doPostBack(id, event);

Comment: add event won't fire the button postback event either...wired.